# Exporting default rigify basic meta human to Unity breaks heirarchy

Tags: rigging, unity, rigify

I am new to rigging and followed a tutorial on using rigify with the basic human rig (no face bones or fingers).

All works well in blender and my rig is generated properly with weights.

However, when I export the fbx to Unity I get this weird seperation between torso and root bones, I did not change any naming just kept everything as default.

I've tried re-doing the process 3 times now, always end up with an issue in Unity.

What could be wrong here?

[image]
[image]

Rigify to Unity error:

> Python: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\MaxNi\AppData\Roaming\Blender
> Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\Rigify-To-Unity-master_*init*_.py",
> line 51, in execute
> ob.data.edit_bones['DEF-shoulder.L'].parent = ob.data.edit_bones['DEF-spine.003'] KeyError:
> 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "DEF-shoulder.L" not found'

Comment: See https://youtu.be/vrN9duEoA6g which is for Blender 2.82. There may be a later version somewhere. The actual export starts at around 3.30.

Comment: @JohnEason this is the one I followed :(

Comment: I don't know Unity at all, but did you check "Only Deform Bones" in the Armature section of the FBX export dialog?

Comment: @JohnEason I understand, thanks for trying to help. I did find an error now given by the rigify to unity addon, not sure if its due to my later version. Added error to edit

Comment: Might be because I tried to simplify the rigify rig, since it generates several bones unity does not use. Will try again after lunch!

Comment: A quick Google for "blender export rigify rig to unity" (without the quotes) brings up quite a few hits including [this](https://github.com/pKrime/Expy-Kit) addon which you may already be using. Good luck!

Comment: I solved it! you cannot change anything from the default rigify rig. so ull have to just accept the extra bones you dont really need.