# Blender doesn't export character animations

Tags: animation

I'm just learning Blender and I've made some animations for a character, but when I export it to FBX and put it into Unity, I only get the character model without animations..

Here are some pictures

[image][image]

Comment: See if [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301200/exporting-default-rigify-basic-meta-human-to-unity-breaks-heirarchy) posting helps.